# Create a command to put letters in different shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am a math teacher and I am currently writing my exercise banks for a course. I use LaTeX for this and I would like to represent the difficulty of an exercise with a particular shape surrounding the letter of the exercise. The following figure illustrates what I have in mind:

[image]

I am a beginner in using Tikz. I can manage to create the shapes (except maybe the last one which is a square and a diamond on top of it), but I have a lot of trouble putting visible text inside them. I would like to be able to create new commands `\easy{}`, `\medium{}`, `\hard{}`, `\vhard{}` in which I would only have to insert the letter (for example, `\easy{a}` ) to get the desired result.

Does anyone have a general structure to propose to solve my problem? I'm not asking to do everything for me, but maybe enlighten me a bit on the structure of the LaTeX code since I'm new to using Tikz.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the TeX code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Mensch Thanks! Right now, I found out how to make the circle : \newcommand\easy[1]{
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};} , but it doesn't work well when I change the ''shape'' parameter. And I'm not too sure how to inverse colors and make the circle black and the interior white.

Comment: The request was to EDIT your question and post it there. And to enable copy&compile you should enter a few more lines, please.

Comment: You can use the [`text`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/text) to change the color of the text of a node (or just use `\color{white}` asnpartnof the text itself). Unless you want to create a new node shape, you're going to have to draw the last one semi-manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I defined a new list environment (called `problems`) with `enumitem`. Then I defined commands `\easy`, `\medium`, `\hard` and `\vhard` which should behave essentially like `\item`, but they add a box around the item's label.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problems]{
    label=\alph*,
}
\newcommand*{\easybox}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline]
        \node[circle, fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries, inner sep=2pt] at (0,0) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand*{\mediumbox}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline]
        \node[fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries, inner sep=3pt] at (0,0) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand*{\hardbox}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline]
        \node[diamond, fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries, inner sep=1.5pt] at (0,0) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand*{\vhardbox}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline]
        \node[fill=black, font=\bfseries, inner sep=3pt] at (0,0) {\phantom{#1}};
        \node[diamond, fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries, inner sep=1.5pt] at (0,0) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand*{\makeproblemcommand}[1]{%
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}{o}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{##1}{%
            \refstepcounter{problemsi}
            \item[\csname #1box\endcsname{\theproblemsi}]
        }{%
            \item[\csname #1box\endcsname{##1}]
        }%
    }%
}
\makeproblemcommand{easy}
\makeproblemcommand{medium}
\makeproblemcommand{hard}
\makeproblemcommand{vhard}
\begin{document}
\begin{problems}
    \easy An easy problem
    \medium A problem
    \hard A challenging problem
    \vhard A very challenging problem
    \easy Another easy problem
    \hard Another hard problem
    \vhard[X] A problem with a different label
\end{problems}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's fantastic! Thank you so much! I managed to make some adjustments so that the size of the shapes remains constant and does not adjust to the size of the letter. And the result is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much for your help.